# How to reference Main once only in this ubuntu terminal command: "javac Main.java && java Main"?

Tags: java, gnome-terminal

I am reviewing a number of different java programs and am trying to work out how I can update the reference to the program name once only instead of twice.  Is there a way to use a variable in a single terminal command? :S

The command I'm trying to improve is of this form:

`javac Main.java && java Main`

I only want to change the reference to Main once instead of typing it twice each time.

Comment: Create a shell script (say compileandrun.sh) like this `javac $1.java && java $1`. Then call it with `compileandrun Main`. You can then do the same with Main2 by running `compileandrun Main2`

Comment: You can alse use a *builder* like maven. Anyway, that is the way to go as soon as you have non trivial programs. Then the command is only `mvn run` and maven knows what needs to be compiled (eventually runs tests) and run the freshly built executable jar

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one line like this:

```
PC=com/mycompany/Main && CN=$(echo $PC | tr / .) && javac $PC.java && java $CN
```

This will work even if you have a package name as it will automatically replace `/` with `.` to build properly the full qualified name of your class. In the example above it will compile the class `com/mycompany/Main.java` then launch `com.mycompany.Main`

**PC**: Refers to the relative path of your class without `.java`, this what you will need to change

**CN**: Refers to the full qualified name of your class automatically built from the previous path

Comment: This works just as I was hoping, and asked.  I think I should explore the shell script idea @jr593 suggested but this is certainly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it as an environment variable. Something like,

```
export CLS=Main # Change Main once
javac $CLS.java && java $CLS # Will use "Main"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest approach is best.  It sounds like you have a bunch of programs to compile and run.  I would suggest you put those names into a text 
file, like this:

```
Main
Foo
Bar
```

and then use some search and replace in the editor to make the text like this:

```
javac Main.java && java Main
javac Foo.java && java Foo
javac Bar.java && java Bar
```

|Then just select the lines to run and paste them into the terminal.

Of course, it depends on your expected workflow, but sometimes the simplest is the best.