# how can i run my java program outside of eclipse on mac

Tags: java

```
package trying;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a=input.nextInt();
        int b=input.nextInt();

        int d=a+b;

        System.out.println(d);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can run it via command line. Try a google search, like _how to run a java program via command line_. Or see [how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line)

Comment: this will even compile and launch your class http://stackoverflow.com/a/37745811/1997376

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360995/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-program-in-java-on-my-mac

Comment: compile by ``javac calculation.java`` and to run ``java calculation`` at terminal

Comment: For the future try to google it at least ^^

Answer (score 0):

First one should compile the java by using this command:

```
javac calculation.java
```

As second step one would run the program with this command:

```
java calculation
```

for a more detailed version of this answere i'll refer to the duplicate post: [How do I compile and run a program in Java on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360995/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-program-in-java-on-my-mac)