# Adding bash function to compile and run java with multiple command line inputs

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to create a bash function to compile and run java code but that is also not restricted to a single command line argument. Thus far I have:

```
run() {
    javac $1.java
    java $1 $2
}
```

The problem is that this only allows for one command line argument

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745334/how-to-reference-main-once-only-in-this-ubuntu-terminal-command-javac-main-jav

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, you can simply write

```
run() {
    javac "$1".java
    java "$1" "${@:2}"
}
```

For POSIX compatibility, you would need something only slightly longer:

```
run() {
    fname=$1
    shift
    javac "$fname".java
    java "$fname" "$@"
}
```